# Creating a session var in dos?

Tags: batch-file

I have a script, it adds a path to path

```
 path=%PATH%;C:\dev\external\stuff\bin
```

After running my bat script a few times i get an error here because PATH is way to long (cause i added the same path X amount of times).

So i tried `myvar="dontdoitagain"` and wrote an if statement. However its always empty, it seems to be cleared when the bat file ends (as oppose to when i reopen the prompt, which is what i do when i get that error).

How do i get that variable to live in session scope rather then bat file scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not defined EXTENDED_PATH (
    set PATH=%PATH%;my_additions
    set EXTENDED_PATH=1
)
```

should work, actually. Unless you use `setlocal` which restricts the lifetime of the variables all variables created remain after the batch exited.

Note: If you actually use DOS this won't work since it relies on functionality introduced in `cmd` with Windows NT 4 roughly 15 years ago. In that case you may need to resort to the following:

```
if %EXTENDED_PATH%==1 goto skip
set PATH=%PATH%;my_additions
set EXTENDED_PATH=1
:skip
```

Comment: I don't know why but this code doesnt work. I get an error in the part of the script i didnt write. I change EXTENDED_PATH to a unique var so theres no interference. The script works correctly with the line in my question. It doesnt like this syntax for some reason

Comment: I tried testing with this and it failed. Without the '('')' around the path it succeed. But googling suggest () is how to use a multiblock if statement. So i am very confused.
if ("1")==("1")(
PATH=%PATH%;C:\dev\external\bin
)

Comment: @acid: Hm, wait a minute. Are you *really* on DOS?

Comment: Not actual dos. What is the windows 7 cmd prompt called?

Comment: `cmd.exe`. Its full Name is actually *Windows Command Processor* if I recall correctly. In any case, then I'm at a loss. I'm fairly sure your problem stemps from elsewhere in the file. If I use the snippet I have given you alone in a batch file it works just fine.